# Most Pythonic and efficient to join list of strings until the length gets too high

Tags: python

Assume I am creating a checkout system for a store. This is a list of the products:

```py
products = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Durian"]
```

And I want to join them with commas. So, I can use this:

```py
", ".join(products) # Returns "Apple, Banana, Cherry, Durian"
```

What if I want to limit the length of the output string? Say, I want to output `"Apple, Banana…"` if the final string is longer than 20 characters?
The problem is, I want to prevent the names from being cut, so I don't want `"Apple, Banana, Cher…"`. In some cases, the strings in `products` may contain commas, so I don't want to split the string with commas.

Comment: When you say *"limit the length of the output string"*, do you want to keep joining subsequent substrings, just limit the lengt hof what gets rendered/printed out? That's what is usually done. (e.g. in pandas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
products = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Durian"]

string = products[0]

for v in products[1:]:
    if len(string) + len(', ') + len(v) <= 20:
        string = string + ', ' + v
    else:
        string = string + '...'
        break

print(string)
```

Output:

```
Apple, Banana...
```

Comment: Just a tiny detail but you forgot the `...` ;)